# Scraping a table from Texas Dept. of Criminal Justice website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The script scrapes a table from the website mentioned, looks at the last 2 columns, takes that information, and then sorts it (and then returns the largest county, and the set of races and their numbers). But, basically, I just wanted to know in which ways I can make this script parallel more closely with the Zen of Python, and if there are any optimizations I could make to the script to make it a little faster. I also know that Python's goal is not to be fast, but if I can make the script faster, I don't see why not (though the main priority is to make it Pythonic).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Scraping information from https://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html"""

import requests, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import defaultdict

url = "https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html"
county = {}


def counties(countyArg):
    """Fills the `county` variable"""
    f = open("counties.txt")
    for line in f.readlines():
        countyArg[line.replace('\n', '').rstrip()] = 0

def scrape(urlArg, countyArg):
    """Scrape Site Based on HTML"""
    races = defaultdict(int)

    page = requests.get(urlArg)
    html = page.content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table')
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        if row.findAll('td')[8].text == 'Black':
            races['black'] += 1
        elif row.findAll('td')[8].text == 'White':
            races['white'] += 1
        elif row.findAll('td')[8].text == 'Hispanic':
            races['hispanic'] += 1

        countyArg[row.findAll('td')[9].text.encode('ascii').rstrip()] += 1

    return races, county

def find_largest(countyArg):
    """find largest county"""
    largestCounty = ''
    largestInmates = 0
    for key, value in countyArg.iteritems():
        if largestInmates < value:
            largestInmates = value
            largestCounty = key
    return largestCounty, largestInmates

if __name__ == '__main__':
    counties(county)
    print county
    scrape(url, county)
    print find_largest(county)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to [PEP 20, the Python Zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), which you seem to be already familiar with,
another must read (and follow) for Python coders is [PEP 8, the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
Many of those recommendations apply to your code,
please read it carefully, I won't repeat them here.

#### Working with resources

In `counties`,
you open a file for reading but you never close it.
You should always close the resources, file handles you open.
But actually, in Python, you should use the `with` syntax, like this:

```
with open("counties.txt") as fh:
    for line in fh.readlines():
        countyArg[line.replace('\n', '').rstrip()] = 0
```

In this form, you don't actually need to close:
Python will automatically close the file handle after leaving the `with` block.

#### Why out-parameters?

It's not clear why you opted for initializing an empty `county` dictionary and then filling it in the `counties` method.
It would be more natural to let `counties` create the dictionary and return it.

#### Avoid global variables

`county` is declared at the outermost scope,
effectively making it a global variable.
Avoid global variables as much as possible.

As hinted earlier,
it would be better to create the dictionary inside a function,
and pass it around to the functions that need it.

For example:

```
load_counties(path):
    counties = {}
    with open(path) as fh:
        for line in fh.readlines():
            counties[line.replace('\n', '').rstrip()] = 0

    return counties

# ....

def main():
    counties = load_counties("counties.txt")
    scrape(url, counties)
    # ....
```

#### Avoid code duplication

Avoid repeated logic like this:

> ```
> for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
>     if row.findAll('td')[8].text == 'Black':
>         races['black'] += 1
>     elif row.findAll('td')[8].text == 'White':
>         races['white'] += 1
>     elif row.findAll('td')[8].text == 'Hispanic':
>         races['hispanic'] += 1
> ```

Not only it is error-prone to repeat `row.findAll('td')[8].text` many times,
it's also inefficient: beautiful soup has to find all `td` elements multiple times.

Refactor to do this only once:

```
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    race = row.findAll('td')[8].text
    if race == 'Black':
        races['black'] += 1
    elif race == 'White':
        races['white'] += 1
    elif race == 'Hispanic':
        races['hispanic'] += 1
```

We can also go one step further:

```
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    race = row.findAll('td')[8].text
    if race in ('Black', 'White', 'Hispanic'):
        races[race.lower()] += 1
```

#### Consider using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html)

The `collections` package has a class that can help you here: [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html).
Instead of doing the counting by yourself,
this handy little utility can do it for you,
it goes something like this:

```
from collections import Counter

# ...

    races = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        race = row.findAll('td')[8].text
        if race in ('Black', 'White', 'Hispanic'):
            races.append(race.lower())

    return Counter(races)
```

That is,
from a list like `['black', 'white', 'black', 'white', 'black', 'hispanic']` it will create `Counter({'black': 3, 'white': 2, 'hispanic': 1})`

#### Use `max` to find the maximum entry of a dictionary

`find_largest` can be simplified using `max`:

```
def find_largest(counties):
    return max(counties.items(), key=lambda pair: pair[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks, already changed the file opening method to the aforementioned suggested method. As for the county dictionary, I am using the variable in other functions, so if I let counties create it, would the other function be able to access it (without using any globals)? Also, how would I let `counties()` create the dict?

Comment: I added a note about that in the "Avoid global variables" section. I added a many other sections too.

Comment: OK thanks. I have one question on the "Use max to find the maximum entry of a dictionary". What does the lambda do (I do know what a lambda *is*, but what is it doing there)? As for all the other suggestions, I have changed them out. I ran my code through a PEP8 checker a few times and fixed any errors that arrived. I'll go ahead and update all my code. EDIT: The `max` function only returns a string of the county. I was hoping to get both variables. Any way of doing that? EDIT: Not only does it only return the key, but it also returns the wrong county...

Comment: The lambda is called with each value in the iterable. It should return a value that will be used to determine the ordering. In this example, the iterable is a list of name-count tuples. So `pair[1]` corresponds to count, and so effectively the dictionary items will be ordered by value. When you say "it doesn't work", I think you're not using exactly what I gave you

Comment: Ah apologies, missed a `.items`. Thanks for all the help. Shortened the code by 6 lines, and shortened the run time from ~2:60 to ~2:59 (haha), among other things.